# Firestore web Could not reach firestore backend

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the error message : `@firebase/firestore: Firestore (4.12.1): Could not reach Firestore backend`

I am building a web app and it was working fine today and after a couple of login / logouts , I started receiving this error message. I have initialized the firestore config again and the problem persists. same error message was being thrown with firestore 4.11.0 version.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same error

Comment: In my app , I had implemented phoneAuth for login and due to multiple login/logout attempts for testing, firebase threw that error. I then logged in with a different number and it was working. For development , I now use a disposable phone number .

Comment: I also have the same error, I'm trying to connect to a database that I already connect with firebase with another app, but the new one has this problem even though most of the code is the same

Comment: Are you using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future viewers, this error occurs when the Firebase SDK is unable to reach the Cloud Firestore service for a variety of reasons. We've since moved from Beta to [General Availability](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates) for the service and SDKs and made several improvements since this was first asked.

A prime reason for this error is network connectivity where we cannot get a response from the service in a reasonable timeframe and then revert to offline mode (if enabled).

Another possible reason in Javascript libraries/frameworks are [messing with functionality](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/634) we rely upon in a now compatible way.

If you continue to encounter this issue and don't believe it's network connectivity relate, post a question on our [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss) or as a Github issue against the relevant client library.